# css and android web application, loading local images

Tags: html, android, css, server-side

how do i load a local image from android assets from a generated (php) server-side html file?

eg.
>

img src="file:///android_asset/calendar-date-icon.png">

-or-

background:#ffffff url(file:///android_asset/calendar-date-icon.png)no-repeat;

cannot get either to work

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths. That might happen because the `img`tag does not support using the `file:` protocol for file discovery. But i'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Resource image is managed by app context (probably because everything are compressed in a single APK file, no longer like the normal filesystem), and you need to acces them like this:

```
AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("calendar-date-icon.png");
```